# Creating an email form in angular similar to Google email form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, email

If we look at google when creating a new email you get this :

[image]

The first thing i would like the accomplish is when an object(recipient) is selected from a list it would be added to the TO: (Aan) field. And it must be possible to remove it.

How could this be done ?

Then i have a second question on how to let the user add some styling to his email set some text bold or create a list ...

At the moment i'm using angularjs and spring boot but can't find any good information about this. Any clues where i should look or use to accomplish this ?

Comment: please post the code you tried so far

Comment: I create a simple form with where input field is the recipient,subject and an textarea for the message. So this is probably not what i would need to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that i get what you are actually asking for.

About your first question if you are looking for a UI solution, you should have a look of something like this: [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/)

About your second question instead you could have a look of something like this: [textAngular](http://textangular.com/)

Let me know if this ask your question.

Comment: Awesome just what i needed. Thanks ! For some reason google hide these from me.

Comment: sometimes is just about how you search them ;)